# how to use python with javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, django-models

I have an object "company". When I use company inside of html, it works fine. But when I tried to use that object inside javascript I get the "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &".

What I am trying to do is getting the objects from db then display them on html page then change up some divs using js.

the url:

```
('^all_companies$', 'companies.views.all_companies')
```

the view:

```
def all_companies(request): 
    companies = Company.objects.all().order_by('id')[:5];   
    return direct_to_template(request, 'all_companies.html', {'companies': companies} );
```

the html:

```
{% block sidebar %}
    <div id="sidebar">
        <!-- like google maps, short list of company info -->
        <ul>
            {% for comp in companies %}
                <li>{{ comp }}</li>                 
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

the js:

```
var tmp = {{ companies }}
```

Comment: What does `{{ companies }}` evaluate to? Javascript doesn't seem to like that syntax.

Comment: You should convert `companies` to JSON - only then JS would be able to read it

Comment: @Greg companies is the model object i get from db..

Comment: @hamczu can you explain a bit more for me please? thank you!

Comment: looks like django syntax, you should probably specify that in your question and tags

Comment: you shuld tag this question with django as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a template filter like that one: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/201/

and use

```
{{ companies | jsonify }}
```

but I'm not sure it's a good idea to do that directly on a db object, it will be better to map them to a simple map of properties you need